# SPARQL query running too slow, when querying, sometimes timesout, is there a way to optimize the query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

My Wikidata Query Service query sometimes takes 35000 milliseconds or 35 seconds to complete. I'm not very adept at SPARQL. The query below does work (except it does duplicates sometimes). I'm wanting to get "famous people" by providing a birthday date and month, of which I get their name, birthday, an image of them (Wikimedia), and occupations. I'm also filtering by persons with birth places in the USA and UK.

I've added a variable called "sitelinks" that I count how many links are dedicated to them as a popularity metric (I'm open to better ideas on this, if there is a better way to gauge popularity).  Is there a way to make this more optimized? Again, the query works, it's just slow.

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel (COUNT(DISTINCT(?sitelink)) as ?sites) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel; separator=", ") as ?occupations) (SAMPLE(?image) as ?uniqueImage)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
      wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
      wdt:P27 ?country ;  # Citizenship
      wdt:P106 ?occupation ;  # Occupation
      wdt:P18 ?uniqueImage .  # Image
     
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
  ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel .
  ?sitelink schema:about ?person .
  FILTER(LANG(?countryLabel) = "en")
  FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel) = "en")

  FILTER(MONTH(?birthdate) = 5 && DAY(?birthdate) = 20)
  FILTER(?country IN (wd:Q30, wd:Q145))

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel ?uniqueImage ORDER BY DESC(?sites)
LIMIT 50
```

If anyone wants to paste the query to the Wikidata Query Service, here is the link
https://query.wikidata.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the site count that's killing your query and I think I resolved the duplicate record issue. Would something like this work for your use-case?

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT 
?person 
?personLabel 
?birthdate 
?countryLabel 
?website
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel; separator=", ") AS ?occupations) 
(MIN(?image) AS ?uniqueImage)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
          wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
          wdt:P27 ?country .  # Citizenship
          
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P856 ?website }  # Official website
  
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
  FILTER(?country IN (wd:Q30, wd:Q145))
  FILTER(LANG(?countryLabel) = "en")
  
  FILTER(DATATYPE(?birthdate) = xsd:dateTime 
        && MONTH(?birthdate) = 5 
        && DAY(?birthdate) = 20)
   
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation .  # Occupation
    ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel .
    FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel) = "en")
  }
  
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image }  # Image

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel ?website
ORDER BY DESC(?website)
LIMIT 50
```

### Edit

If you do need the site count though you might be able to use something like this

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT 
?person 
?personLabel 
?birthdate 
?countryLabel 
(COUNT(DISTINCT ?sitelink) AS ?sites) 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel; separator=", ") AS ?occupations) 
(MIN(?image) AS ?uniqueImage)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
          wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
          wdt:P27 ?country .  # Citizenship
          
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image }  # Image

  ?sitelink schema:about ?person .
  
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
  FILTER(?country IN (wd:Q30, wd:Q145))
  FILTER(LANG(?countryLabel) = "en")
  
  FILTER(DATATYPE(?birthdate) = xsd:dateTime 
        && MONTH(?birthdate) = 5 
        && DAY(?birthdate) = 20)
   
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation .  # Occupation
    ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel .
    FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel) = "en")
  }
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel
ORDER BY DESC(?sites)
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: I'm still getting 35-second to 50-second queries.  I think, there really is just no good way to reduce the time to 10 seconds or less.  I would like to use such a query on a website I'm developing, but I might just be forced to use an inferior API instead due to the slowness of Wiki Data Service.

Also the site count, was just my way of gauging popularity, since I don't know what other metric I could use. The idea is to show the more popular people first.

Comment: Oh wow, 10 seconds? Yeah, at that point, your best optimization might be to resort to prayer. I have heard Buddhism is pretty efficient if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of little improvements:

1. You don't need do use `rdfs:label` if you already use `SERVICE wikibase:label {...}`, except if you want to force the English label to be specified in the item or if you want to use the variables in the `SELECT` part.
2. Instead of filtering a posteriori the values for `?country` with `FILTER(...)`, you can use `VALUES ?country { wd:Q30 wd:Q145 }`.

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel (COUNT(DISTINCT(?sitelink)) as ?sites) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel; separator=", ") as ?occupations) (SAMPLE(?image) as ?uniqueImage)
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
          wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
          wdt:P27 ?country ;  # Citizenship
          wdt:P106 ?occupation ;  # Occupation
          wdt:P18 ?uniqueImage .  # Image
  
  ?sitelink schema:about ?person .
  ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel .
  FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel) = "en")
  FILTER(MONTH(?birthdate) = 5 && DAY(?birthdate) = 20)
  VALUES ?country { wd:Q30 wd:Q145 }
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel ?uniqueImage ORDER BY DESC(?sites)
LIMIT 50
```

I don't think you can do much better, by experience I can tell you that `schema:about` property is very resource-demanding.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, that does indeed improve efficiency, by about half, but at the expense of data loss.  The popularity metric I used is now zero so the people are not rank ordered by popularity, and occupations is empty.

Comment: @Travis Sorry, I didn't see you were using `?occupationLabel` in the header. Also, I removed the `schema:about` part by mistake. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Indeed, I had a feeling the schema:about was going to be an efficiency killer. That's why I'm open to better ideas on getting back people by popularity.  I don't know of any other ideas to measure popularity.  It appears I just maybe doomed to have a slow query.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

It's true that it's unlikely that the query can be optimised much more than what `logi-kal` did. However you could look at the number of social media followers that a user has `wdt:P8687` as a proxy for their popularity, however imperfect.

This would yield a query like this, which takes me 7-8s to run:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?countryLabel ?followers ?uniqueImage
WHERE {
  
  VALUES ?country {wd:Q30 wd:Q145}
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;  # Instance of human
      wdt:P569 ?birthdate ;  # Date of birth
      wdt:P27 ?country ;  # Citizenship
      wdt:P8687 ?followers; # Social Media Followers 
      wdt:P18 ?uniqueImage .  # Image

  FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?birthdate), "-05-20"))
 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?followers)
LIMIT 50
```

Notice that Louis Theroux is British *and* American, hence why he appears twice. You can do a `GROUP_CONCAT` to fix the issue.

You could also consider pulling some of the data and run it in a local database that you host, whether a SPARQL database or some other type.
That way you'd be able to add any metric or combination thereof to the data.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even think about social media followers as a metric of popularity.  This does bring the query down significantly.  It is truly unfortunate that Wiki Data Service is so slow.

Comment: I was able to shave down a couple seconds using the Group Concat you suggested.  I did it on the country label

(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?countryLabel; SEPARATOR=", ")

and then did a group by before the order by
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?followers ?uniqueImage

That seemed to have shaved off a couple seconds.  Thanks for the suggestion.